# Change Background color of grid row when selected

Tags: c#, wpf, datagrid, wpf-controls

My `itemscontrol` is currently loading each row correctly.  I am trying to get it to change the background color of each row when the user selects it.

```
<Grid>
                    <Grid.RowDefinitions>
                        <RowDefinition Height="100" />
                        <RowDefinition Height="30" />
                        <RowDefinition Height="*" />
                    </Grid.RowDefinitions>
                    <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                        <ColumnDefinition Width="*" />
                    </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                    <Grid Grid.Row="0">
                        <Border BorderBrush="#BBBDBF" Background="#F4F4F4" BorderThickness="0,1,0,1" Margin="10,10,10,10"/>
                        <Image  HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="10,0,0,0"  Height="38" Width="38" Source="C:\Users\linda_l\Pictures\Cloud upload\database (1).png" />
                        <TextBlock  FontSize="50" Foreground="#4092C2"  Margin="60,0,0,0" HorizontalAlignment="left" Height="69" >Databases</TextBlock>
                    </Grid>

                    <Grid Background="White" Grid.Row="1">

                        <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                            <ColumnDefinition Width="10" />
                            <ColumnDefinition Width="*" />
                            <ColumnDefinition Width="*" />
                            <ColumnDefinition Width="*" />
                            <ColumnDefinition Width="70" />
                            <ColumnDefinition Width="10" />
                        </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>

                        <Border BorderBrush="#BBBDBF" BorderThickness="0,0,0,1" Grid.Column="1"  />
                        <Label Grid.Column="1" Content="Server Name" VerticalAlignment="Bottom" FontWeight="Bold" Foreground="#4092C2" />

                        <Border BorderBrush="#BBBDBF" BorderThickness="1,0,0,1" Grid.Column="2" />
                        <Label Grid.Column="2"  Content="Source Database"  VerticalAlignment="Bottom" FontWeight="Bold" Foreground="#4092C2" />

                        <Border BorderBrush="#BBBDBF" BorderThickness="1,0,0,1" Grid.Column="3"  />
                        <Label  Grid.Column="3"  Content="Destination Database"  VerticalAlignment="Bottom" FontWeight="Bold" Foreground="#4092C2" />

                        <Border BorderBrush="#BBBDBF" BorderThickness="1,0,0,1" Grid.Column="4" />
                        <Label  Grid.Column="4"  Content="Status"  VerticalAlignment="Bottom" FontWeight="Bold" Foreground="#4092C2" />

                    </Grid>

                    <ItemsControl x:Name="itemscntrl"  ItemsSource="{Binding DatabaseServers}" Background="White" BorderBrush="WhiteSmoke" BorderThickness="0" Grid.Row="2" Margin="0,5,0,0">
                        <ItemsControl.ItemTemplate>
                            <DataTemplate>                               

                                <Grid x:Name="grd"  Background="White" > 

                                    <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                                        <ColumnDefinition Width="10" />
                                        <ColumnDefinition Width="*" />
                                        <ColumnDefinition Width="*" />
                                        <ColumnDefinition Width="*" />
                                        <ColumnDefinition Width="70" />
                                        <ColumnDefinition Width="10" />
                                    </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                                    <Image Source="{Binding StatusImage}" Height="10" Width="10" />
                                    <Label Grid.Column="1" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Content="{Binding ServerName}" />
                                    <Label Grid.Column="2" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Content="{Binding SourceDatabase}" />
                                    <TextBox x:Name="dst"  Grid.Column="3"  Text="{Binding DestinationDatabase , Mode=TwoWay, UpdateSourceTrigger=LostFocus}" VerticalAlignment="Top" />
                                    <Label  Grid.Column="4"  Content="{Binding Status}" VerticalAlignment="Top" />
                                    <Button Grid.Column="4" BorderThickness="0" HorizontalAlignment="Center"  Width="50" Margin="3" Content="{Binding Status}" Command="{Binding EnabledCommand}" CommandParameter="{Binding}" />
                                </Grid>
                                <DataTemplate.Triggers>
                                    <DataTrigger Binding="{Binding selected }" Value="True">
                                        <Setter Property="Background" Value="Yellow" TargetName="dst" />
                                    </DataTrigger>
                                </DataTemplate.Triggers>
                            </DataTemplate>
                        </ItemsControl.ItemTemplate>
                    </ItemsControl>
                </Grid>
```

Which currently looks like this:

[image]

I tried adding a `DataTemplate.Triggers` but it doesn't seam to do anything.   How exactly do you detect that a row in a itemscontrol has been selected?  The only examples I have found use a `datagrid`.   I tried changing mine to a `datagrid` instead of the `itemscontrol`, but then the it wouldn't load the data.

Datagrid:

```
 <DataGrid x:Name="grd"  Background="White" DataContext="{Binding DatabaseServers}" Grid.Row="2"> 


                                    <Image Source="{Binding StatusImage}" Height="10" Width="10" />
                                    <Label Grid.Column="1" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Content="{Binding ServerName}" />
                                    <Label Grid.Column="2" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Content="{Binding SourceDatabase}" />
                                    <TextBox x:Name="dst"  Grid.Column="3"  Text="{Binding DestinationDatabase , Mode=TwoWay, UpdateSourceTrigger=LostFocus}" VerticalAlignment="Top" />
                                    <Label  Grid.Column="4"  Content="{Binding Status}" VerticalAlignment="Top" />
                                    <Button Grid.Column="4" BorderThickness="0" HorizontalAlignment="Center"  Width="50" Margin="3" Content="{Binding Status}" Command="{Binding EnabledCommand}" CommandParameter="{Binding}" />
                                </DataGrid>
```

Just shows a bunch of lines there is no data in each row.

I am very new to WPF so I cant really figure out what I am doing wrong here.

Comment: @SriramSakthivel I am not using a datagrid I am using a grid so this does not help.  I already tried that one an hour ago as well :)

Comment: My mistake. Reopened the question.

Comment: Why you don't use a datagrid and customise your selected row as you want

Comment: I tried changing it to a datagrid and my data wouldn't load.

Comment: ItemControls don't have Selected Items, you need to use a ListBox, or a ListView instead. Then apply the style to the ListBoxItem.

Comment: can you just give us how to use Datagrid it can be  aproblem of dataContext

Comment: It probably is but if as you say there is no selected row on grid.  I am going to have to figure out how to get datagrid to show data.   I just think that grid looks nicer.

Comment: If you want i can give you a simple exmample on how to display data on datagrid

Comment: is it me or cant you have a editable text box and a image as a column in the row?

Comment: So if i understand you want a grid with 6 columns one of is editable an the other is an image

Comment: I actually have one with a picture, one is editable and the last one is a button.  let me upload a picture.

Comment: Then you want somthing like this window

Comment: that's what it looks like currently. using a Grid.  If I change it to datagrid its not showing any data I am still working on it.  But I suspect that datagrid is not an option, as far as I can see you can display buttons, textboxes and images in a datagrid.

Comment: You need to use a `DataGrid`. Just because you couldn't get it to work on your first attempt is no reason to give up with what was the right solution. Just go to MSDN or find online tutorials and get the `DataGrid` working.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is what you want using `DataGrid` i m using `MVVM`

***Window.xaml***

```
<Grid Margin="10">
        <StackPanel Orientation="Vertical">
            <Label Content="DataBases" Width="150" Height="50" HorizontalAlignment="Left" FontSize="20"/>
            <DataGrid Name="DgDataSource" AutoGenerateColumns="False" CanUserAddRows="False" ItemsSource="{Binding SourceData}">
                <DataGrid.Columns>
                    <DataGridTextColumn Header="ServerName" Binding="{Binding ServerName}" Width="2*"/>
                    <DataGridTextColumn Header="SourceDatabase" Binding="{Binding SourceDatabase}" Width="2*"/>
                    <DataGridTextColumn Header="DestinationDatabase" Binding="{Binding DestinationDatabase}" Width="2*"/>
                    <DataGridTemplateColumn  Width="*" Header="Status" >
                        <DataGridTemplateColumn.CellTemplate>
                            <DataTemplate>
                                <Button Content="{Binding Status}" Command="{Binding EnabledCommand}"></Button>
                            </DataTemplate>
                        </DataGridTemplateColumn.CellTemplate>
                    </DataGridTemplateColumn>
                </DataGrid.Columns>
            </DataGrid>
        </StackPanel>

    </Grid>
```

***View Model***

```
 public class WindowViewModel
    {
        public ObservableCollection<DataSource> SourceData { get; set; }

        public WindowViewModel()
        {
            Initialize();
        }
        private void Initialize()
        {
            SourceData = new ObservableCollection<DataSource>
            {
                new DataSource() {Status = "Stop", ServerName = "Test 1", SourceDatabase = "Unknown",DestinationDatabase = "blabla....."},
                new DataSource() {Status = "Work", ServerName = "Test 2", SourceDatabase = "Unknown",DestinationDatabase = "blabla....."},
                new DataSource() {Status = "Stop", ServerName = "Test 3", SourceDatabase = "Unknown",DestinationDatabase = "blabla....."}
            };
        }
    }
```

***Model***

```
 public class DataSource
    {
        public string Status { get; set; }

        public string ServerName { get; set; }

        public string SourceDatabase { get; set; }

        public string DestinationDatabase { get; set; }

    }
```

[image]

Comment: wow you derive more then just a 1 up and an except for putting that together.    Its about the same as what I have come up with, I also found DataGridTemplateColumn :)

Comment: hhh y re welcome bro ... ok then tell your friends to give me some up votes :p

Comment: for the command you better add a relay command if you need how to fix it just tell me